# Selected ForeColor Not Displaying In Access ComboBox

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have a ComboBox on an Access form whose ForeColor property is set to a specific hex value. The RowSource is loaded with 2 fields from a particular table - the first field is an ID and hidden and the second is displayed for the user to see. When I load the RowSource with one table the ComboBox displays the information for the second field in the assigned color. If I replace the RowSource of the same ComboBox with a different table (same structure - 1st field an ID and hidden and 2nd field a value to be displayed) the color of the displayed field is black. All property settings remained the same, including the ForeColor setting. The only change made was to load a different table as the RowSource.

This problem occurs for some tables but not others. I don't see any reason that the table should be able to make a change in the ForeColor in the ComboBox.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple problem that I should have checked before entering this question, but may be helpful for others.

Any fields that were used in the ComboBox to be displayed that override the selected ForeColor setting had a value of "@" in the Field Format property in the table. Removing the "@" in the Field Format property and leaving it blank solved the problem.